# Converting 32-bit WAV to 16-bit WAV in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I am using the [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/src/recorder.js#L156) library to output a WAV file in Chrome, but it's currently a 32-bit WAV file.  I'm looking at this code here, but am not sure what to change to output a 16-bit WAV file.  The audio file is mono (single-channel).  I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821255/converting-a-32-bit-wave-form-to-a-16-bit-wave-form) that I need to scale the values by [32,767](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995259/naudio-convert-32-bit-wav-to-16-bit-wav) and then cast to 16-bit integer?

Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296645), I am not trying to downsample, or change the number of audio channels.  I want to change the bit depth.

Comment: Where you read that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrease bitrate on WAV file created with recorderjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296645/decrease-bitrate-on-wav-file-created-with-recorderjs)

Answer (score 0):

recorder.js actually does output a 16-bit WAV file, as can be seen from the code [here](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/src/recorder.js#L186).  I didn't realize this because I was opening the files in Audacity, which automatically changed it to 32-bit WAV format.  But opening in VLC and selecting Media Information showed the correct results.